# MongoDB runCommand value only

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to execute a MongoDB runCommand query and as an output I only want the value. Currently its returning nested attributes name too.

Sample matching record:

```
{
   "_id":"123",
   "name": "Emp1",
   "department": {
      "deptName":"dept1",
      "type": "xyz"
    }
}
```

Query I am trying:

```
db.employee.runCommand( {
  find: db.employee.getName(),
  filter: {'name':'Emp1','_id':'123'},
  projection: {_id:0,'department.deptName':1}
});
```

Query Response:

```
{
"cursor": {
    firstBatch" : [
      {
         "department":{
              "deptName":"dept1"
            }
       }
   ],
   .
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Is there any way I can skip the parent name from attribute and get the department name directly like

```
"firstBatch" : [  {
     "deptName":"dept1"
    }
]
```

Any pointers will be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: commands that return cursors like `find/aggregate` is not good idea to use them with `runCommand`. The reason is that you will have to call `getMore` commands to get the rest of the documents. I think you should just use the find/aggregate method of your driver. For the projection maybe try  `{"deptName" : "$department.deptName", "department" : "$$REMOVE"}`

Comment: It worked with aggregate query.